# how to search a file content in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have posted data to elastic search i.e username , resume(type: blob) .
now i want to search a particular world from resume so for that i fire following query in elasticsearch tool :

```
{"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "match": {
         "filecontent": "Documentation"
      }
    }
  ],
  "must_not": [],
  "should": []
}
},"from": 0,
"size": 10
}
```

but No results are there: my resume contains "**Documentation**" word.

so please suggest me the how to construct a query in filecontent.
Help?

here is my data which I posted in elastic search:

```
{
  "took": 112,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
   "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
 },
 "hits": {
  "total": 1,
  "max_score": 0.6931472,
  "hits": [
  {
    "_index": "profiles",
    "_type": "resume",
    "_id": "2013",
    "_score": 0.6931472,
    "_source": {
      "filetype": "doc",
      "firstname": "akash",
      "filecontent": "PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000!\u00002oWf\u0001\u0000\u0000¥\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0013\u0000\b\u0002[Content_Types].xml ¢\u0004\u0002( \u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Does your `Index` contain `filecontent` field? as per your question there should be 2 fields `username` and `resume`!

Comment: @avr, yes, it contains "filecontent" field.